# Composer - extension iconv is missing

Tags: php, apache, composer-php, iconv, nette

I'm running Manjaro linux and I have installed apache 2.4.10-1 with php 5.5.15-1 and php-composer 1.0.0.alpha8.458-1.

I want to download project with composer by this command

```
composer create-project nette/sandbox TaskManager
```

but I'm getting error with ext-iconv

```
- nette/neon v2.2.1 requires ext-iconv * -> the requested PHP extension iconv is missing from your system.
- nette/nette v2.2.0 requires ext-iconv * -> the requested PHP extension iconv is missing from your system.
```

But in my php.ini i have enabled iconv extension

```
extension=iconv.so
.
.
[iconv]
iconv.input_encoding = ISO-8859-1
iconv.internal_encoding = ISO-8859-1
iconv.output_encoding = ISO-8859-1
```

In my php scripts I can use iconv function without any problem.

When I run php -m i see iconv in list with other modules

Any idea where could be problem?

**Edit**:
When I run php -i from cli, I got this:

```
Configuration File (php.ini) Path => /etc/php
Loaded Configuration File => /etc/php/php.ini
Scan this dir for additional .ini files => /etc/php/conf.d
Additional .ini files parsed => (none)
```

And in this config file is iconv enabled.

Even when I run

```
php -d error_reporting=E_ALL -r 'echo iconv("UTF-8", "ASCII//TRANSLIT", "Žluťoučký kůň\n");'
```

it executes properly and prints "Zlutoucky kun".

Answer (score 23, accepted):

So i found out, that composer uses different php config file, which is stored in

```
/usr/share/php-composer/php.ini
```

there I just added following line

```
extension=iconv.so
```

And everything works!

Comment: There's a report in the Arch Linux bugtracker about this issue: https://bugs.archlinux.org/task/42467

Comment: After reading this I found something useful and extended it.

Look at this gist: [composer.php.ini](https://gist.github.com/auipga/508a3221d70ac275a3eb86b9217e22c5)

Answer (score 11):

I solved this problem uncomment the line

```
ext=iconv
```

in /etc/php/php.ini
Working on manjaro linux

Comment: I try to edit in /etc/php/php.ini then uncomment extension=iconv

Comment: Worked like a charm! (arch/manjaro) - beware there was no "ext" but "extension"

Answer (score 6):

In WHM on Centos7 it worked for me.

```
yum install ea-php72-php-iconv
```

You can replace your php version instead of **php72**

Comment: Thank you, the more popular answer didn't work for me. /usr/share/php-composer/php.ini did not exist. I do think it's worth mentioning that you should use your php version
```
yum install ea-php(whatever your php version is)-php-iconv
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are using [PHPBrew](https://github.com/phpbrew/phpbrew) run this command to install `iconv` extension:

```
phpbrew ext install iconv
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm also running Arch (under the Manjaro stack, also using `pacman`.)

If the php.ini file has the correct extensions declared, but you still get the error, try the `composer` flag `--ignore-platform-req=`. In your case, probalby something like:

```bash
composer create-project nette/sandbox TaskManager --ignore-platform-req=ext-iconv
```

Additionally, make sure you never run `composer` as root, but as web, then `php`

```
su httpd -c 'php composer create-project nette/sandbox TaskManager --ignore-platform-req=ext-iconv'
```

If `php` is executing the `composer` command, then Composer may have a better time looking at the more relevant php.ini file.

---

The tendency for false alarms is arguably one more reason to not use `composer` when creating your own projects for others.

Bear in mind, `composer` was created as a kind of "nanny" to automatically install dependencies... because web admins don't know how to read the docs and do that on their own, right? It is primarily useful for web developers who don't know web admin, or are denied `root` access by their employers or customers, but only work higher in the stack.

Because of Composer's purpose, it may trigger a lot of false warnings. This is probably why it has the `--ignore-platform-req=` flag. Don't be afraid to use this as it is one of `composer`'s redeeming qualities.